# link click event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Link "Goods" click event is not working after "Shops" clicked

```
<div class="i_find">
    <div class="replaced_link">Goods</div>
    <div class="link_container"><a href="#" class="a_shops">Shops</a></div>
</div>
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/01j2s7xj/12/

Comment: You should really post your full code into the question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use event delegation here:

```
$("body").on('click','.a_shops',function(){ 
    $('.i_find div:eq(0)').replaceWith('<div class="link_container"><a class="a_goods" href="#">Goods</a></div>');
    $('.i_find div:eq(1)').replaceWith('<div class="replaced_link">Shops</div>');

});

$("body").on('click','.a_goods',function(){
    $('.i_find div:eq(0)').replaceWith('<div class="replaced_link">Goods</div>');
    $('.i_find div:eq(1)').replaceWith('<div class="link_container"><a class="a_shops" href="#">Shops</a></div>');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97ow0zmv/)**